# Magento Mobile and Desktop with same database

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

We have a website developed in Magento (ex: www.example.com) and we are planning to develop mobile website which will run on sub-domain (ex: m.example.com).

```
Desktop version - www.example.com
Mobile version  - m.example.com
```

We want to use same Magento database for both Mobile and Desktop sites. As I know we can't use same database for both sites as everything in Magento depends on `{{base_url}}`. I am unable to find if there are any ways to do this. Please help us with your ideas.

#### Edit:

I found this **[link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup)** which explains how to add multiple sites with same database but it seems to be applicable only for localization purpose because in my case, I need to have **two different codes** for desktop and mobile sites, with same database.

Any help would be appreciated.